# resultactions set httpstatuscode to specific value

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Is it possible to set the httpstatus code to something else or create a dummy ResultActions object with specified values?

I have to match the resultset with a specific status code, so I want to set it manually rather than coming from post request

```
ResultActions results = mockMvc.perform(url("")
                 .headers("")
                 .contentType("")
                 .accept("")
                 );
```

result is returning 204 but I want to set 200 or create totally new object with specified values.

Comment: I think it's possible, you can set manually your HTTP reponse. can you post a little sample of code in order to see the problem ?

Comment: You can add .andExpect(status().isOk()) or other status code in the resultActions object. But it brings you the result of your request. If there is no content in your request you will get 204

Comment: It is giving AssertionError: expected 200 but was 204

Comment: Yes, if want your test to pass you have to find the good status corresponding to 204, 200 is status().isOk()...